# ORDER BY result from two table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

Im make a live search function at my site

```
$result = 
      mysql_query("SELECT word as my_field FROM keywords 
                   WHERE word LIKE ('" . $search . "%') 
                   UNION 
                   SELECT term as my_field FROM popular_search 
                   WHERE term LIKE ('" . $search . "%') GROUP by my_field LIMIT 10");
```

I'm trying get result from two tables, as I can see this working fine, but in both tables, **keywords** and **popular_search**, I have field **amount** so I need to sort this query above by amount, so I can have relevant and popular result. I'm trying with ORDER by amount DESC , but this not working...

Comment: Please use PDO and parametrized queries instead of the `mysql_` extension; the latter’s deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :

```
$result = 
mysql_query("SELECT my_field, SUM(amount) sum_amount
    FROM (
        SELECT word as my_field, amount
        FROM keywords 
        WHERE word LIKE ('{$search}%') 
        UNION 
        SELECT term as my_field, amount
        FROM popular_search 
        WHERE term LIKE ('{$search}%')
    ) tab
    GROUP BY my_field
    ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
    LIMIT 10");
```

What the query do :

1. Search word and amount from keywords based on $search
2. Search term and amount from popular_search based on $search
3. Union both queries above and alias name as tab
4. Group tab by my_field
5. Order by SUM(amount) DESC
6. Limit 10 to return first 10 records

Hopefully this help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `amount` column in your `SELECT` list:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT word as type, amount
                       FROM keywords 
                       WHERE word LIKE ('" . $search . "%') 
                       UNION 
                       SELECT term as type, amount
                       FROM popular_search 
                       WHERE term LIKE ('" . $search . "%') 
                       GROUP by type 
                       ORDER BY amount DESC
                       LIMIT 10");
```

FYI, the `GROUP BY` clause above only applies to the `popular_search` query, not the `UNION`. If you want it to apply to both, you need to put the `UNION` in a subquery, and then do: `SELECT <columns> FROM (<subquery>) x GROUP BY type`. You probably also want to use `SUM(amount)` or `MAX(amount)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting from the selection:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT amount, … FROM keywords
        WHERE word LIKE CONCAT(:search, '%')
    UNION SELECT amount, … FROM keywords
        WHERE term LIKE CONCAT(:search, '%')
        GROUP BY type LIMIT 10
) ORDER BY amount
```

I’m not sure whether that works in MySQL, though.